# How can I capture video frame by frame using python on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, video

I would like to know how could I capture video frame by frame from a camera connected to my Ubuntu system using python? What library would I need to use? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best module to stream videos from camera is the `opencv` module, references [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/index.html), tutorial [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/PythonInterface). Specifically use `cvCaptureFromCAM` [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#cvCaptureFromCAM) to acutally capture the stream.

Answer (score 2):

Image capture can be done on Linux using [V4L](http://linuxtv.org/wiki). Though neither is specifically for this purpose, both [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) and [Pygame](http://www.pygame.org/) have an interface to V4L. Here's some references for using each:

- **OpenCV** - [documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/highgui_reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=capture#CaptureFromCAM) & [sample code](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/python/capture-cam.py?rev=616)
- **Pygame** - [documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/camera.html) & [sample code](http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/camera/CameraIntro.html)